# Detecting when ZMQ_RATE limit or ZMQ_SNDHWM have been reached

Tags: zeromq

Is there a way to programatically know when a pgm zeromq socket has stopped forwarding information because the ZMQ_RATE limit has been reached or if it is dropping data because the ZMQ_SNDHWM limit has been reached. There is a zmq_socket_monitor function call that allows the user to see events like client connect and client disconnect. I am thinking that there should be a similar construct for the rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q :**
> <sub>*"Is there a way to programatically know when a ... zeromq socket has stopped forwarding ... because ..." ?*</sub>

**A :**
 to the best of my knowledge and knowing [limits thereof](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/zeromq/topusers), there is no such way implemented so far.

If bets on reasoning for not having a way, I'd put my few cents on

(a)
such feature having zero-( if not negative )-effects on ZeroMQ primary goals, that are maximum performance, minimised resources needs to achieve performance and minimum latency

(b)
anyone, capable of providing a stable & acceptable implementation of this feature into the core & c-API could've been warm welcome to implement it, yet no one has put one's efforts into developing & testing & accepting it so far, so we stay in 2022-Q1 still in square number one